# Limiting a filtered query

Tags: query, pre-get-posts

I'm struggling with this query. I have a page where I will show products launched from last month and this current month. (http://the.nett.mx/innvictus/wp/) Everything works great, but when I apply the same date limits while filtering the query by brand ("marca") it doesn't work. My guess is that I'm using twice the "value" in the `meta_query`. Here I show you my `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    global $fecha_actual, $fecha_anterior;

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'producto' ) {

        $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array( 
            'field_1'   => 'marca', 
            'field_2'   => 'mes'
            );

        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

        foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {

            $name = filter_input( INPUT_GET, $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            if( empty($_GET[ $name ]) ) {
                continue;
            }


            $value = explode(',', $_GET[ $name ]);

            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => $name,
                'value'     => $value
            );


        } 

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        $query->set('meta_key','fecha');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order','ASC');

        if( !empty($_GET[ 'marca' ]) ) {
            echo "entrada ".$fecha_actual. " & ". $fecha_anterior;

            $query->set('value',array($fecha_anterior, $fecha_actual));
            $query->set('compare','BETWEEN');  
            $query->set('type','DATE'); 


            }

    }

}
```

Should I use another technique to "filter the filtered" query? Thx in advance!

p.s. fechaanterior is "previous date" and fecha actual is "current date", defined by `$fecha_actual = current_time('Ymt');` 
`$fecha_anterior = date('Ymd', strtotime("first day of last month"));)` in case you ever need to get the current and previous month

Comment: your code too many using globals and it is unreliable, and just use one of both filter_input and $_GET.

Comment: Thx Jevusca, but that's how I found a way to use a parameter in the url in the form /marca?=adidas , so how can I achieve filtering both conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem was related that one custom field was a taxonomy, so, as I was using the archive page for that custom post type, I only needed to filter the query looking for the date limits.

```
$fecha_actual = current_time('Ymt'); //t regresa el ultimo día del mes
$fecha_anterior = date('Ymd', strtotime("first day of last month"));

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10, 1);

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    global $fecha_actual, $fecha_anterior;

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'producto' && is_archive()) {


        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query'); 

       if( !empty($_GET[ 'marca' ]) ) {

             $meta_query[] =   array(
                    array(  
                        'key' => 'fecha',
                        'value' => array($fecha_anterior, $fecha_actual),
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'type' => 'DATE'
                     )
             );

        }        



        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        $query->set('meta_key','fecha');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
        $query->set('order','ASC');


    }

}
```